# Is it possible to link to, include and use a static library without extra include headers/files?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I want to make a static library so that my other projects can use the same code.

Is it possible to link to the static library in the other projects, without having extra include/header files or is there a better way for this?

Comment: The header files *should* contain information on how to call functions.  Compilers need this information when parsing a source file (translation unit).

Comment: Is including the headers slowing down your build time (like in the order of minutes)?

Comment: The answer is yes, but you wouldn't want to. Headers roadmap what is available in a library (be it static or dynamic). Someone, somewhere, needs to tell consumers of that library what is available from said-same. How much you divulge is a matter of design. Regardless, this has an overpowering, putrid aroma of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if ever I've seen one. What is the root problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No no, the thing is it seems like a lot of work making the header files for the library, but R Sahu and WhozCraig made it clear why it's good. Now that I think about it it's actually just taking the header file from the library and make it a include file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to link to the static library in the other projects, without having extra include/header files?

It is possible. You have to declare the funtions that are defined in the .lib manually before you can use them.
It is errorprone and is not advised.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the header file that contains the key functionality in your static library, or are you talking about header files of all the dependencies and/or internals used by the static library?

You should have a header (or more than one) to show the facilities of your static library to the code that uses it. (It's possible to omit this but then your static library has no declared interfaces).

But, it's best practice to *not* include any unneeded headers - those that are used by the library's internal implementation. Often you can move dependency includes into the static library's .cpp files so they aren't exposed by your library's headers.